# После выполнения cmd команды через os.popen необходимо автоматически вводить ответ в stdin

Tags: python, cmd

Программа запускает `cmd` команду `comp "{path_1}" "{path_2}`, а та в свою очередь пишет в `stderr` (в cmd выводится: `Сравнить другие файлы [Y(да)/N(нет)] ?`), после чего ожидает ввода информации в `stdin` со стороны пользователя в `cmd`. Вопрос: можно ли как-то перенаправить ввод, чтобы автоматически вписывать ответ в консоль без человеческого участия? (попытки `print(sys.stdin.write('N'))` не привели к желаемому результату)

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

def run_command(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    data = process.communicate()
    for line in data:
        cur_line = line.encode('cp1251').decode("cp866")
        if 'Не удается найти или открыть' in cur_line:
            print(sys.stdin.write('N'))
        elif 'Различия не найдены' in cur_line:
            continue
        else:
            print(cur_line)


command = "dir /B /S /AD"
dirs_inside = [line.encode('cp1251').decode("cp866") for line in os.popen(command)]
for dir_ in enumerate(dirs_inside):
    dirs_inside[dir_[0]] = dir_[1][:-1]
cur_dir = os.getcwd()
all_dirs = [cur_dir] + dirs_inside

disk = 'H'
command_template = 'comp "{path_1}" "{path_2}"'
for dir_ in all_dirs:
    path1 = disk + dir_[1:]
    path2 = dir_
cur_command = command_template.format(path_1=path1, path_2=path2)
print(cur_command)
run_command(['comp', path1, path2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
out, err = process.communicate(input='N', timeout=3)
```

Вот в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.communicate) подробней. Насчет попытки `sys.stdin.write()` есть такое предупреждение:

> **Warning** Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.